# « Un regard très affûté sur les civils » : sens etc.?

Tags: sens, adjectifs, participe-passé, formulation

> [...] Ce qui est assez fascinant avec Marcel Ouimet - et ça, tous les historiens le disent en France -, c'est qu'au-delà des combats qu'il relate au plus près, il a un regard très **affûté** sur les civils. On le voit dans plusieurs de ses reportages et encore plus dans ses lettres... C'est intéressant parce que depuis 2014, tout se focalise sur les civils. Lui, il a fait ça 70 ans avant. [...] —Jean-Baptiste Pattier au sujet de Marcel Ouimet
>   ds. [*Lapresse.com*](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/201906/01/01-5228453-debarquement-de-normandie-ici-marcel-ouimet-qui-vous-parle-de-france.php), je souligne.

Pour le sens au figuré le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affut%C3%A9/4) dit « fin, rusé, adroit » puis, « sur cet emploi, cf. [*affûter*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affut%C3%A9/3)<sup>3</sup> I A rem. Les écrivains semblent jouer librement avec l'une ou l'autre des possibilités de rattachement ». On y trouve alors : « On a aussi rattaché à un emploi fig. de *affûter*<sup>3</sup>, le part.-adj. affûté « rusé » (cf. [affûter](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affut%C3%A9/2)<sup>2</sup> I C rem. 2 et *affûté*) ». Puis à la remarque 2 : « 2. *Nouv. Lar. ill.* signale un *affûter* « rendre rusé » (cf. [*affût*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aff%C3%BBt/1) 2C 2, *être d'affût* : ["Être rusé, malin, sur le qui-vive, avoir l'œil au guet.", France]). Cet emploi, mal établi, s'expliquerait mieux si on le rattachait à futé « malin ». »

---

De quel sens d'*affûté* s'agit-il ici et qu'est-ce que ça signifie, y a-t-il un rattachement particulier, s'agit-il d'une métaphore ; est-ce le *regard* ou l'« affûtage », d'une certaine manière, qui soit « sur les civils » si l'on compare avec « tout se focalise sur les civils » ?

Answer (score 3):

Pour moi il pose un regard aiguisé sur les civils, il arrive très clairement à identifier leurs problématiques et à les relater avec exactitude dans ses reportages, articles. Il y a une connotation d'habitude dans cette formulation, il est rompu à l'exercice et le fait bien.

Ici, comme tu l'as remarqué, "affûté" est sans doute mal employé, même s'il est dans le sens futé, malin. Un autre adjectif tel que "aiguisé" serait plus juste dans ce contexte.

***EDIT :***

Le contexte de l'expression se prête plus aisément à l'utilisation d'aiguisé que d’affûté. D'un point de vue purement linguistique l'utilisation des deux termes est parfaitement correcte étant tout deux synonymes, c'est le contexte et les connotations qui entourent chaque mot qui va favoriser l'utilisation de l'un plutôt que de l'autre.

Ainsi, l'utilisation d'aiguisé, qui a une connotation plus marquée sur les *sens*,  *l'habitude*, me semble plus appropriée. Affûté a une connotation très marquée sur la "*préparation*" qui n'est pas l'intention de base véhiculée par la phrase.

Dans la phrase "...il a un regard très affûté sur les civils.", on sent clairement la sensibilité aiguë, l'habitude de l'auteur qu'il a pour décrire  la situation des civils pendant les conflits.

Comment: Comme on pourrait dire "d'un œil averti", cela serait sans doute également plus approprié.

Comment: Vu les sens concrets assez similaires de _aiguisé/affûté_, pourquoi penses-tu que le premier serait plus juste ? C'est la cooccurrence avec _regard_ qui te semble plus usitée ou c'est une sens au figuré qui diffère et si oui lequel ?

Comment: @suiiurisesse je vous ai répondu dans l'EDIT car pas assez de place dans les commentaires. Vous avez raison ce sont les connotations entourant chacun des mots qui va favoriser l'utilisation de l'un plutôt que de l'autre. Ainsi, il y a une forte connotation de "préparation" derrière le sens d'affûté que je ne retrouve en priorité pas dans la phrase. Ainsi, je favoriserai l'utilisation d'aiguisé dans cet exemple.

Answer (score 1):

Un couteau bien affûté est tranchant, il permet de découper en lames très fines, facilement.

De même, un regard affûté permet de distinguer, de séparer, d'analyser en détails, avec la même facilité. Éventuellement, il sera aussi tranchant, sans indulgence, dans ses jugements.

*Affûté* me parait parfaitement employé ici.

*Aiguisé* proposé dans la première réponse me parait aussi parfaitement utilisable, pour les mêmes raisons.